# PHP: Как в односвязном списке из середины удалить элемент?

Tags: php, алгоритм, list, односвязный-список

Есть вот такой пример кода:

/list.php

```
class Node
{
    public $data;
    public $next;

    function __construct($data, $next = null)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->next = $next;
    }
}
```

/index.php

```
require_once('list.php');
$ari = new Node('Ari');
$malcolm = new Node('Malcolm', $ari);
$pete = new Node('Pete', $malcolm);
$ricky = new Node('Ricky', $pete);
$sean = new Node('Sean', $ricky);

cut($sean, 3);


function cut($head, $levelToCut)
{

    $i = 1;
    $temp = $head;

    while (!empty($temp->next)) {

        if ($i == $levelToCut) {

            $temp = $temp->next;
        }

        if($i !== 1) {
            $temp = $temp->next;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Пропустить Пита с помощью ($i == $levelToCut) удается, но вот как сделать так, чтобы после его обнуления не пропала остальная часть списка, а приклеилась на освобожденное Питом место? Ума не приложу. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Непонятно что удаётся если сейчас функция ничего не делает а $temp всегда содержит последнее звено.

Comment: @InDevX в условии if ($i == $levelToCut) ловлю ноду до Пита и после.. Мне нужно его исключить, так, чтобы конец сдвинулся и приклеился к началу так как будто Пита не было. Единственный способ передвигаться по нодам в цикле, который я нашёл - $temp = $temp->next, но так у меня съедается начало списка.. В итоге мне непонятно, как добиться желаемого..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть неплохой способ разбираться с такими задачками. Нарисуйте ваш список на бумаге и посмотрите на него. Как вырезать Pete?

```
 ,------------. 
 |Sean        | 
 |------------| 
 |next = Ricky| 
 `------------' 
        |       
 ,-----------.  
 |Ricky      |  
 |-----------|  
 |next = Pete|  
 `-----------'  
        |       
,--------------.
|Pete          |
|--------------|
|next = Malcolm|
`--------------'
        |       
   ,--------.   
   |Malcolm |   
   |--------|   
   |next Ari|   
   `--------'   
        |       
 ,-----------.  
 |Ari        |  
 |-----------|  
 |next = null|  
 `-----------'
```

Я думаю вы уже сообразили. Надо чтобы Ricky ссылался на Malcolm. Точнее Ricky->next = Pete->next.

Получается вам надо добраться до нужного элемента, имея под рукой переменную, которая ссылается на предыдущий элемент и просто заменить next у этого предыдущего элемента.

Рисунки помогают лучше понять, что вы делаете. Например посмотрите на рисунок ещё раз и подумайте, как удалить первый элемент?

Comment: Тут проблема как-раз в реализации, человек не понимает как сделать, а не что надо сделать

Comment: @InDevX но в его коде нет присваивания next и цикл не прерывается, когда он доходит до нужного элемента. Выглядит так, будто проблема именно в непонимании того, что надо делать.

Comment: В коде и нет потому что проблема в непонимании как это сделать) А с рисунками полностью согласен, так всегда легче воспринимать и понимать.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин абстрактно что делать, мне понятно, нужно малкольму в -> next положить вместо Pete, Ricky, а Пита удалить. Но как технически осуществить не врубаюсь.. При проходе в цикле начало сьедается, соответственно, как потом "склеить" разъединенные концы списка? Пробовал химичить с двумя копиями $head, в котором одной сохраняю начало, а второй - конец, но так тоже не выходит.

Comment: @Valentin доходите до нужного элемента (это у вас получилось), а дальше next этого элемента присваиваете next'у предыдущего. И прерываете цикл (break), ведь остальные элементы вам трогать не надо. Ваша идея о склеивании концов ошибочна. Вы не разделяете список на "концы". Вы просто заменяете next и всё "склеивается" само собой.